# How to add a new server to a list with text and buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a dynamic list that shows if the server is running, every time i add a new server the list has to show the status of the server with labes and  buttons, how do i create a list or grid that adds buttons/labels automatically when it detects i added a new server?

Currently looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epjao.png

```
SqlConnection condb = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename =|DataDirectory|\\ConnectionStrings.mdf; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlDataAdapter test = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From [Table]" ,condb);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        test.Fill(dt1);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
        {

            string Ip= row["Ip"].ToString();
            string Id = row["User"].ToString();
            string Port = row["Port"].ToString();
            string Password = row["Password"].ToString();

            string credentials = $"server={Ip}; user id={Id}; port={Port}; Password={Password}";

            //Opens the connection and sends "show slave status" command.
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(credentials);
            con.Open(); //Opens the connection
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, con); //Sends the query to "show slave status"
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            adp.Fill(ds); //Fill Dataset.
            dt = ds.Tables[0]; //Then assign table to dt.


            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows) //Checks the server if it is running or not.
            {
                string value = dataRow.Field<string>("Slave_IO_Running"); //Looks for "Slave_IO_Running" status.


                if (value == "Yes")
                {
                    Label1.Text = "WORKING";
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "REPLICATION ERROR";
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: If you managed to get data on the screen, it would seem you would have knowledge how to add more of them

Comment: Not dynamically with Labels and Buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your GridView / Table you are using to display your server list in an ASP:UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlServerList" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%-- YOUR GRIDVIEW HERE --%>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then, in your code-behind, when you call the method / fire the event to add a new one to the list, call the UpdatePanel update method:

```
upnlServerList.Update();
```

If this isn't what you are looking for, you could also look into ASP:Repeaters that would allow you to bind a list to the repeater and display the list in a different format.